# Tumblr custom domain not redirecting properly

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, dns, cname, tumblr

I decided to host my blog at Tumblr, using their custom domain setup (`http://blog.smokingfishgames.com/` instead of `http://smokingfishgames.tumblr.com`).  However, it's been 72 hours and I'm still getting spotty redirection.

It works some of the time--I go and see the page and blog, and it's all fine. However, it occasionally just stops working and redirects back to my web host, which is a directory with nothing but a single file called `BUGGER.html` (which I stuck in to make sure that it was my web host and not some Tumblr empty directory).

Clearing the Chrome DNS cache makes the problem go away--for a while. After a few minutes, or an hour, or however long, I'll start seeing `BUGGER.html` again. I clear the cache, and poof, the blog shows up.

The thing that's curious to me is that when I clear the cache and get `BUGGER.html` again (which happens occasionally), I can look at my Chrome DNS cache and see

```
assets.tumblr.com   UNSPECIFIED 
blog.smokingfishgames.com   UNSPECIFIED 
www.tumblr.com  UNSPECIFIED
```

**IP addresses and expiration times omitted for brevity's sake**--if they're important I'm sure I can replicate the issue.

This implies, to me anyway, that my browser is reaching Tumblr but getting bounced back to my web host.  Any reason why this would be happening, or is this a normal symptom of DNS propagation?  If it is a problem, should I be bothering Tumblr or my host with it, or is this something I can fix myself?

Comment: You should include details of how you are pointing your domain to tumblr, please take a screenshot or write the setup in tumblr and that of the domain on the registrar, as both will need to be set.

Comment: My registrar's DNS is 
`A  82.197.131.96  3600

CNAME  domains.tumblr.com  3600

MX  blog.smokingfishgames.com  3600  10` and Tumblr has `blog.smokingfishgames.com` plugged in.  When I click 'test your domain' it says that my domain 'is pointing to Tumblr!', very cheerfully.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it--I had to delete my A record.